# The best way to pass data between clients in a room

Tags: unity, unity-networking

I am developing a backgammon game in Unity and tried to use Photon. But I could not find a step by step help for it and I also know that photon in real-time and it syncs data over 10 times per second. but I need to sync data after each moves.

Would you please show me the best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Photon Turnbased instead of Photon Realtime. They have a step by step guide as well.

**Photon**

> Photon Turnbased offers everything that Realtime has but is geared towards games with less interaction between players (turnbased or not) and games that can be paused and picked up later on (asynchronously). It makes more use of Webhooks (e.g. to store a room's state) and WebRPCs.

Turnbased Intro: 
https://doc.photonengine.com/en/turnbased/current/getting-started/turnbased-intro

**Parse**

> The Parse platform provides a complete backend solution for your mobile application. Our goal is to totally eliminate the need for writing server code or maintaining servers.

Unity Guide: 
https://parse.com/docs/unity/guide